# Is there a theorem like this in analysis?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ (possibly at the end points as well), then $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(x)dx$ is also continuous for some $x \in (a,b)$.

I know I am missing some other assumptions that are needed because the above statement is not true in general since the continuity of $f$ only yields differentiability, which we know is not enough for continuity (Weiestrass Functon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've gotten yourself confused - the Weierstrass function is continuous but not differentiable, not vice versa. In fact differentiability implies continuity in general; so the indefinite integral of any continuous function is always continuous by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Well, the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is used in some applied mathematics, so while not strictly a function in standard analysis, it does have its uses and introduces a discontinuity in $F(x)$.

Comment: You are right. I have really made a blunder this time.

Comment: You mean to say the indefinite integral of any continuous function is differentiable, as a consequence of FTC?

Comment: @Arthur, I thought the Dirac Delta is not a function...

Comment: @treble, he probably does mean that.

Comment: @treble: oops, fixed.

Comment: @sidht And I do say it's not a function, if you read my comment. But it still has its uses, for instance as modeling the charge of an electron at a point in space.